# Generating SQL update from Google spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet organised like so:

```
       A         B         C    
  |---------+---------+---------|
1 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
  |---------+---------+---------|
2 | value1  | value2  | value3  |
  |---------+---------+---------|
```

I want to generate the following SQL query on a cell:

```
update TableX set Column1 = value1, Column2 = value2, Column3 = value3
```

I know it can be done like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("update TableX set ",A1," = ",A2,", ",B1," = ",B2,", ",C1," = ",C2)
```

But is there a better way to do this, one that would easily allow me to add or remove new rows? I'm looking for something in the lines of this (function below made up for example):

```
=CONCATENATE("update TableX set ",JOINTWOROWS(" = ", ", ",A1:C1,A2:C2))
```

Where arguments 1 and 2 would be in-column separator and between-column separator.

I also want to be able to add new rows, that would get new update queries automatically, such as this:

```
       A         B         C         D
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
1 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
2 | value1  | value2  | value3  | update1 |
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
3 | value1a | value2a | value3a | update2 |
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
4 | value1b | value2b | value3b | update3 |
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
5 | value1c | value2c | value3c | update4 |
  |---------+---------+---------+---------|
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. Could you give an example of what it would look like when you "add rows"?

Comment: Edited to include example with additional rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in D1 of your example with the extra rows populated:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1;"Column4";IF(LEN(A:A)*LEN(B:B)*LEN(C:C);"update TableX set "&A1&" = "&A:A&", "&B1&" = "&B:B&", "&C1&" = "&C:C;IFERROR(1/0))))
```

Comment: I loved the part where you can define in a single cell where you want that formula to repeat itself along an array, thanks! =]

I'm not too fond of the fact that I have to manually enter " = " and ", " for each column, but I don't think I'll be getting anything simpler than this.

Comment: I guess the next step would be to use Google Apps Script to write a custom function, which would make your made-up function... functional. And this custom function could also be written to output an array, like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

An untested idea: Add a new row (row number 3) with the formula

> =CONCATENATE(", ";A1;" = '";A2;"')

Drag this row to the right as long as you like.

In the update cell formula, use:

> =CONCATENATE("update TableX set ";A3:XYZ3)

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good idea, but then for every new row I'll have to include a second row with the secondary concatenation. I'll wait to see if someone comes up with a more straightforward idea.